# How to find out where a program is looking for libraries

Tags: linux

The other day I came across a linux command that let me see where a program is expecting to find its libraries. It is very useful to solve library dependency problems for not so popular or proprietary software. I used `ldd`, it was very informative, but missed one crucial piece of information for me:

`ldd -v ./my_executable`
 
gave good information for libraries that `my_executable` can link to. 
But for those it can not link/find, `ldd` only gave information like:

`<a_library_name.so.version> => not found`

What I want is, instead of "not found", I want to see

`not found at /path/to/<a_library_name.so.version>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need the `strace` command
Take a look here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/

Comment: `strace -e open ./my_executable` shows pretty much what I want to see. I had the impression that the command I was looking for gives more concise output though. I accept this as the answer anyway.

Answer (score 5):

on linux you can use the LD_DEBUG. This [link](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The information about library paths is stored in `/etc/ld.so.conf`:

```
/usr/local/lib64
/usr/local/lib
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
# /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib64 and /usr/lib gets added
# automatically by ldconfig after parsing this file.
# So, they do not need to be listed.
```

See [man ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) for more information.

Comment: I am aware of this. However, some programs will look for library from `/path/to/installation/dir/libraries`. What worse, this path can be hard-coded, and it is different from the actual installation path.

Comment: But why should `ldd` list all directories where it is looking? You can get this info from `/etc/ld.so.conf` and you can also look if  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set. See [this documentation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).